# EntityState - Como funciona

Tags: .net

O que seria e pra que serve o EntityState do Entity Framework?

Quando ele pode ser aplicado? Algúem tem algum exemplo de porque usar ele?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pra você entender como funciona o EntityState você tem que entender o ciclo de vida da entidade (Entity Lifecycle).

Qualquer operação CRUD é feita através do contexto (context) que criamos do banco de dados. Esse contexto guarda uma referência para todos objetos e suas modificações nas propriedades (change tracking).

Então, quando você pega um objeto existente do contexto, ele se torna uma entidade e tem seu estado monitorado. Se você modifica a entidade editando suas propriedades, você a passará para o estado de modificada. Depois, salva as mudanças no contexto e ele no banco de dados.

**Exemplos de uso**

Adicionando uma nova entidade ao contexto:

```
var cliente = new Cliente { Name = "Marcos" }; 
context.Entry(cliente).State = EntityState.Added; 
context.SaveChanges();
```

Adicionando uma entidade ao contexto que não esta sendo monitorada por ele:

```
context.Entry(ClienteExistente).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
```

Adicionando as modificações de uma entidade ao contexto:

```
context.Entry(ClienteExistente).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Mudar o estado da entidade (você pode alterá-lo):

```
// Mudando para unchanged
context.Entry(existingBlog).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
```

Por fim, vale lembrar que o uso do EntityState explicitamente não é obrigatório, você pode usar apenas quando necessário.

Comment: Qual vantagem em utilizar a mesma? Por exemplo, no primeiro item, não daria no mesmo aplicar: Cliente cli = new Cliente();
            cli.nome = txtNome.Text;
            cli.email = txtEmail.Text;

            Cliente c = ctx.Clientes.Add(cli);

            ctx.SaveChanges();

Comment: Como ficaria um exemplo de update com EntityState? (onde eu queira atualizar apenas 1 campo, por exemplo)

Comment: Daria na mesma. O comando Add esta fazendo a mesma coisa que aquele comando. Você esta trabalhando com o estado da entidade da mesma forma. A questão não é vantagem ou desvantagem e sim entender como funciona o Entity Framework.

Comment: Entendi, tem como colocar um exemplo de atualizar um field no modelo que citou acima: context.Entry(ClienteExistente).State = EntityState.Modified;

Comment: Você mudará quantas propriedades que quiser na view e no controller você usa o exemplo que dei "adicionando as modificações...) seguido de um contexto.SaveChages()

Comment: Se voce quiser um exemplo completo posso te mostrar no chat

Comment: Oi Sim, porque eu fiz um exemplo de update e está funcionando, e gostaria de saber da maneira de fazer via EntityState.Modified e a diferença técnica ou em performance de um pro outro!

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57953/discussion-between-luhhh-and-fabri-damazio).